# User-defined sorting comparison using AutoIt

Tags: sorting, autoit

PHP has [usort](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and Java has the [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)) interface.

These allow you to create a simple function that compare two Objects, Strings, etc. without getting involved in the details of the sort implementation.

---

*Generally, the comparison function looks something like this:*

```
// Return value:
//    Negative value: a before b
//    Positive value: b before a
//    Zero:           strings are equal
function compare(String a, String b) {
    return toLowerCase(a) - toLowerCase(b);
}
```

*... and you can be as simple or as fancy as you like with your comparisons.*

---

**Is there anything in AutoIt that does this?**

The documentation is great, and the Help File is great, but I cannot find anything that allows me to define a custom comparison function. (I will reimplement Quicksort if necessary, but with a framework as full-featured as AutoIt, I feel like I must just be overlooking something.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "*Is there anything in AutoIt that does this?*"

Example as per [`_ArrayMultiColSort()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/155442-arraymulticolsort-new-release-15-sep-15/) :

```
#include <Array.au3>
#include "ArrayMultiColSort.au3"

Global Const $g_sHeaderRow = 'category|value'
Global Const $g_aSortOrder = [ _
                                [0, 'critical,important,regular'], _
                                [1, 1] _
                             ]
Global       $g_aArray     = [ _
                                ['critical',  7], _
                                ['important', 2], _
                                ['important', 6], _
                                ['regular',   2], _
                                ['critical',  5], _
                                ['regular',   9] _
                             ]

_ArrayMultiColSort($g_aArray, $g_aSortOrder)
_ArrayDisplay($g_aArray, @ScriptName, '', 0, Default, $g_sHeaderRow)
```

Returns:

```
critical  7
critical  5
important 6
important 2
regular   9
regular   2
```

Answer (score 1):

While there does not seem to be anything build into AutoIt, continued research revealed several very useful libraries the community has created.

Below is one called `_ArrayCustomSort.au3` by Erik Pilsits. Script has been copied at the end of this post for reference. Original can be found here:

https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/83626-natural-order-string-comparison/

#### Usage:

```
#include <File.au3>
#include "_ArrayCustomSort.au3"

; Directory to list files
Local $dir = "C:\Windows"
Local $arr = _FileListToArray($dir, "*")
_ArrayDelete($arr, 0)

; Here is the name of the user-defined sorting function!
_ArrayCustomSort($arr, "_MyBasicStringCompare", 0)
_ArrayDisplay($arr)

; Now you can put all your crazy sorting logic in here!
Func _MyBasicStringCompare($s1, $s2)
   Return StringCompare($s1, $s2)
EndFunc
```

---

#### Include Library:

```
#include-once
#include <Array.au3>

; #FUNCTION# ====================================================================================================================
; Name ..........: _ArrayCustomSort
; Description ...: Sort a 1D or 2D array on a specific index using the quicksort/insertionsort algorithms, based on a custom sorting function.
; Syntax ........: _ArrayCustomSort(Byref $avArray, $sSortFunc[, $iDescending = 0[, $iStart = 0[, $iEnd = 0[, $iSubItem = 0]]]])
; Parameters ....: $avArray             - [in/out] Array to sort
;                  $sSortFunc           - Name of custom sorting function. See Remarks for usage.
;                  $iDescending         - [optional] If set to 1, sort descendingly
;                  $iStart              - [optional] Index of array to start sorting at
;                  $iEnd                - [optional] Index of array to stop sorting at
;                  $iSubItem            - [optional] Sub-index to sort on in 2D arrays
; Return values .: Success - 1
;                  Failure - 0, sets @error:
;                  |1 - $avArray is not an array
;                  |2 - $iStart is greater than $iEnd
;                  |3 - $iSubItem is greater than subitem count
;                  |4 - $avArray has too many dimensions
;                  |5 - Invalid sort function
; Author ........: Erik Pilsits
; Modified ......: Erik Pilsits - removed IsNumber testing, LazyCoder - added $iSubItem option, Tylo - implemented stable QuickSort algo, Jos van der Zande - changed logic to correctly Sort arrays with mixed Values and Strings, Ultima - major optimization, code cleanup, removed $i_Dim parameter
; Remarks .......: Sorting function is called with two array elements as arguments. The function should return
;                  0 if they are equal,
;                  -1 if element one comes before element two,
;                  1 if element one comes after element two.
; Related .......:
; Link ..........:
; Example .......: No
; ===============================================================================================================================
Func _ArrayCustomSort(ByRef $avArray, $sSortFunc, $iDescending = 0, $iStart = 0, $iEnd = 0, $iSubItem = 0)
    If Not IsArray($avArray) Then Return SetError(1, 0, 0)
    If Not IsString($sSortFunc) Then Return SetError(5, 0, 0)

    Local $iUBound = UBound($avArray) - 1

    ; Bounds checking
    If $iEnd < 1 Or $iEnd > $iUBound Then $iEnd = $iUBound
    If $iStart < 0 Then $iStart = 0
    If $iStart > $iEnd Then Return SetError(2, 0, 0)

    ; Sort
    Switch UBound($avArray, 0)
        Case 1
            __ArrayCustomQuickSort1D($avArray, $sSortFunc, $iStart, $iEnd)
            If $iDescending Then _ArrayReverse($avArray, $iStart, $iEnd)
        Case 2
            Local $iSubMax = UBound($avArray, 2) - 1
            If $iSubItem > $iSubMax Then Return SetError(3, 0, 0)

            If $iDescending Then
                $iDescending = -1
            Else
                $iDescending = 1
            EndIf

            __ArrayCustomQuickSort2D($avArray, $sSortFunc, $iDescending, $iStart, $iEnd, $iSubItem, $iSubMax)
        Case Else
            Return SetError(4, 0, 0)
    EndSwitch

    Return 1
EndFunc   ;==>_ArrayCustomSort

; #INTERNAL_USE_ONLY#============================================================================================================
; Name...........: __ArrayCustomQuickSort1D
; Description ...: Helper function for sorting 1D arrays
; Syntax.........: __ArrayCustomQuickSort1D(ByRef $avArray, ByRef $sSortFunc, ByRef $iStart, ByRef $iEnd)
; Parameters ....: $avArray   - Array to sort
;                  $sSortFunc - Name of sorting function.
;                  $iStart    - Index of array to start sorting at
;                  $iEnd      - Index of array to stop sorting at
; Return values .: None
; Author ........: Jos van der Zande, LazyCoder, Tylo, Ultima
; Modified.......: Erik Pilsits - removed IsNumber testing
; Remarks .......: For Internal Use Only
; Related .......:
; Link ..........;
; Example .......;
; ===============================================================================================================================
Func __ArrayCustomQuickSort1D(ByRef $avArray, ByRef $sSortFunc, ByRef $iStart, ByRef $iEnd)
    If $iEnd <= $iStart Then Return

    Local $vTmp

    ; InsertionSort (faster for smaller segments)
    If ($iEnd - $iStart) < 15 Then
        Local $i, $j
        For $i = $iStart + 1 To $iEnd
            $vTmp = $avArray[$i]
            For $j = $i - 1 To $iStart Step -1
                If (Call($sSortFunc, $vTmp, $avArray[$j]) >= 0) Then ExitLoop
                $avArray[$j + 1] = $avArray[$j]
            Next
            $avArray[$j + 1] = $vTmp
        Next
        Return
    EndIf

    ; QuickSort
    Local $L = $iStart, $R = $iEnd, $vPivot = $avArray[Int(($iStart + $iEnd) / 2)]
    Do
        While (Call($sSortFunc, $avArray[$L], $vPivot) < 0)
            $L += 1
        WEnd
        While (Call($sSortFunc, $avArray[$R], $vPivot) > 0)
            $R -= 1
        WEnd

        ; Swap
        If $L <= $R Then
            $vTmp = $avArray[$L]
            $avArray[$L] = $avArray[$R]
            $avArray[$R] = $vTmp
            $L += 1
            $R -= 1
        EndIf
    Until $L > $R

    __ArrayCustomQuickSort1D($avArray, $sSortFunc, $iStart, $R)
    __ArrayCustomQuickSort1D($avArray, $sSortFunc, $L, $iEnd)
EndFunc   ;==>__ArrayCustomQuickSort1D

; #INTERNAL_USE_ONLY#============================================================================================================
; Name...........: __ArrayCustomQuickSort2D
; Description ...: Helper function for sorting 2D arrays
; Syntax.........: __ArrayCustomQuickSort2D(ByRef $avArray, ByRef $sSortFunc, ByRef $iStep, ByRef $iStart, ByRef $iEnd, ByRef $iSubItem, ByRef $iSubMax)
; Parameters ....: $avArray  - Array to sort
;                  $iStep    - Step size (should be 1 to sort ascending, -1 to sort descending!)
;                  $iStart   - Index of array to start sorting at
;                  $iEnd     - Index of array to stop sorting at
;                  $iSubItem - Sub-index to sort on in 2D arrays
;                  $iSubMax  - Maximum sub-index that array has
; Return values .: None
; Author ........: Jos van der Zande, LazyCoder, Tylo, Ultima
; Modified.......: Erik Pilsits - removed IsNumber testing
; Remarks .......: For Internal Use Only
; Related .......:
; Link ..........;
; Example .......;
; ===============================================================================================================================
Func __ArrayCustomQuickSort2D(ByRef $avArray, ByRef $sSortFunc, ByRef $iStep, ByRef $iStart, ByRef $iEnd, ByRef $iSubItem, ByRef $iSubMax)
    If $iEnd <= $iStart Then Return

    ; QuickSort
    Local $i, $vTmp, $L = $iStart, $R = $iEnd, $vPivot = $avArray[Int(($iStart + $iEnd) / 2)][$iSubItem]
    Do
        While ($iStep * Call($sSortFunc, $avArray[$L][$iSubItem], $vPivot) < 0)
            $L += 1
        WEnd
        While ($iStep * Call($sSortFunc, $avArray[$R][$iSubItem], $vPivot) > 0)
            $R -= 1
        WEnd

        ; Swap
        If $L <= $R Then
            For $i = 0 To $iSubMax
                $vTmp = $avArray[$L][$i]
                $avArray[$L][$i] = $avArray[$R][$i]
                $avArray[$R][$i] = $vTmp
            Next
            $L += 1
            $R -= 1
        EndIf
    Until $L > $R

    __ArrayCustomQuickSort2D($avArray, $sSortFunc, $iStep, $iStart, $R, $iSubItem, $iSubMax)
    __ArrayCustomQuickSort2D($avArray, $sSortFunc, $iStep, $L, $iEnd, $iSubItem, $iSubMax)
EndFunc   ;==>__ArrayCustomQuickSort2D
```