# Using native Windows natural order sorting in a custom program

Tags: c#, c++, sorting, winapi, dllimport

As a programmer, you have probably had to use or create some kind of string comparison function. Usually, these are pretty simple:

```
function compare(s1, s1) { return s1.toLowerCase() - s2.toLowerCase(); }
```

This works great for the vast majority of cases. However, Windows *(XP and later)* sorts files differently -- and better! -- than a poor ASCII implementation.

**How can I create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example of native Windows natural order sorting in a custom program?**

Everything I have read points to using the `StrCmpLogicalW` function in `shlwapi.dll`. That's great! But how can this function be used inside a custom C/C++ program?

I am ***not*** interested in re-implementing the compare function. I have already seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5641272/2657515), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4165694/2657515), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/248603/2657515), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5427506/2657515), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23818825/2657515). These are no doubt very close approximations, but I just want to link or call the Windows API function in my program.

Here are some other things I have researched and tried already:

- reading the [documentation on `shlwapi.dll` and `StrCmpLogicalW` from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-strcmplogicalw)
- finding a (supposedly) complete program posted from [an earlier Q&A here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5818643/2657515)
- compiling several small code samples for Visual Studio 2010 Express, both C++ and C# versions (`fatal error C1190: managed targeted code requires a '/clr' option`... *really?*)
- compiling several small code samples for Visual Studio 2012 Express, because some article said this would get rid of the earlier compile error about the `/clr` option, but just got a bunch of different compile errors instead
- tried compiling several small code samples for Eclipse C++ with MinGW

When I first started looking into this, I thought, "It's just the Windows API, this will be easy!" I have yet to come up with a working program in any language.

I have been doing C/C++ and Unix/DOS/Windows shell scripting for a long time, and using an API has never been so irksome. Shame on you, Microsoft.

---

Also, I've already read the rants about ASCII sorting, but thank you. These contained some fertile soil for some good thinking.

https://blog.codinghorror.com/sorting-for-humans-natural-sort-order/

http://weblog.masukomi.org/2007/12/10/alphabetical-asciibetical/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "shlwapi.lib")

#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

bool str_cmp_logical(std::wstring const &lhs, std::wstring const &rhs)
{
    return StrCmpLogicalW(lhs.c_str(), rhs.c_str()) < 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::wstring> foo{
        L"20string", L"2string", L"3string", L"st20ring", L"st2ring",
        L"st3ring", L"string2", L"string20", L"string3"
    };

    for (auto const &f : foo)
        std::wcout << f << L' ';
    std::wcout.put(L'\n');

    std::sort(foo.begin(), foo.end(), str_cmp_logical);

    for (auto const &f : foo)
        std::wcout << f << L' ';
    std::wcout.put(L'\n');
}
```

Output:

```
20string 2string 3string st20ring st2ring st3ring string2 string20 string3
2string 3string 20string st2ring st3ring st20ring string2 string3 string20
```

---

Trying to compile the code with MinGW failed, because the version of `<shlwapi.h>` that comes with its package `w32api` doesn't provide a prototype for `StrCmpLogicalW()`. When I declared it myself i got

```
C:\MinGW\bin>"g++.exe" -lshlwapi C:\Users\sword\source\repos\Codefun\main.cpp
C:\Users\sword\AppData\Local\Temp\ccMrmLbD.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x23): undefined reference to `StrCmpLogicalW(wchar_t const*, wchar_t const*)'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So the libraries shipped with MinGW don't seem to be aware of `StrCmpLogicalW()`.

It should work with Mingw-w64, though.

Comment: This looks great, and matches very closely some of the early examples I found. But it does not compile until VS2010. Eclipse with MinGW. says "ignoring #pragma comment  [-Wunknown-pragmas]"

Comment: "But it does not compile until VS2010." Does not compile ... what are the error messages? Why (TF) are you using VS2010 in 2017? "Eclipse with MinGW says "ignoring #pragma comment [-Wunknown-pragmas]" Add `shlwapi.lib` as linker input any other way your compiler/linker understands?

Comment: Trying to add this library is part of the point of this question. The file `shlwapi.h` is easy to find, but the `shlwapi.lib` file does not exist on my system, and I am not familiar with how to include it. My programming background is primarily Linux, and the Windows API ecosystem is somewhat mystifying.

Comment: @JonathanDavidArndt You need to install the [Windows Platform SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) to get the files needed to write Windows programs (like `shlwapi.h` and `shlwapi.lib`). When installing, say that you want the files necessary for creating Windows Desktop apps in C++.

Comment: @RaymondChen Will those `lib`s be compatible with MinGW? I'm just wondering ... why would MinGW come with its own set of WinAPI headers and libs if it were much simpler to just use the PlatformSDK provided by MS?

Comment: @Swordfish I'm guessing that MinGW includes a custom copy of the header files because they needed to tweak them to work with g++. But they didn't need to make any tweaks to the libraries, so they're expecting you to get the libraries from the Platform SDK. I'M JUST GUESSING.

Comment: @RaymondChen As to http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MinGW it ships with its own set of import libraries.

Answer (score -1):

Turns out, DLLs can be called easily with AutoIt or AutoHotKey.

I have distilled [this post from the AutoIt forums](https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/166944-natural-sort-order-strcmplogicalw-call-help/?do=findComment&comment=1220651) into a minimal working example:

```
Func _StrCmpLogicalW($s1, $s2)
   Return DllCall('shlwapi.dll', 'int', 'StrCmpLogicalW', 'wstr', $s1, 'wstr', $s2)[0]
EndFunc
```

And here is a minimal example distilled from [this archive post on the AutoHotkey forums](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/32820-natural-sorting/page-2):

```
_StrCmpLogicalW(s1, s2)
{
   VarSetCapacity(ws1, StrLen(s1)*2+1,0), DllCall("MultiByteToWideChar", "UInt",0, "UInt",0, "UInt",&s1, "Int",-1, "UInt",&ws1, "Int",StrLen(s1)+1)
   VarSetCapacity(ws2, StrLen(s2)*2+1,0), DllCall("MultiByteToWideChar", "UInt",0, "UInt",0, "UInt",&s2, "Int",-1, "UInt",&ws2, "Int",StrLen(s2)+1)
   return DllCall("Shlwapi.dll\StrCmpLogicalW","UInt",&ws1,"UInt",&ws2)
}
```

That's it! The function takes two stings and returns `-1/0/+1` like ever other comparison function in the world.

Combine this with a sorting algorithm (such as [`_ArrayMultiColSort()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52353688/2657515), [`_ArrayCustomSort()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52435425/2657515) for AutoIt) and now you can [Quicksort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) entire lists.

*(Please, do not use [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). Think of the children.)*

Comment: What kind of bot are you making :).

Comment: This was actually inspired by a list of music files that was copied onto a USB player that reads the files sequentially as they were written. My naive ASCII comparison was working great! ... as long as tracks were numbered with leading zeros. There was one very large folder that was playing out of order, and it was because tracks were not numbered, and all the files were named funny.

Comment: Ah, I always just sort by last modified date, so I get them in the order they were added to the file system.

Comment: Question makes no mention of AutoIt. Calling a winapi function is indeed trivial.